# simple_form text input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm switching my application over to use `simple_form` but I'm a little confused about how to display a text input. For instance when I do the following:

```
f.input :foobar # <textarea name = "model[foobar]"></textarea>
```

I get a textarea instead instead in input w/ a type of text. How can I force simple_form to output a text input?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

it's happening because the field is a `text` column in the database, rather than `string`/`varchar`/etc., you can override the default like so:

```
f.input :foobar, :as => :string
```

You can read about all the mappings in the [simple_form readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/README.md) under "Mappings/Inputs available".

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wish that were in the Readme. The Readme doesn't even mention the word "textarea" or the "as: :string" option at all.

Answer (score 9):

I will update the answer to this question, because the new way to do that with simple_form is like this:

```
f.input :foobar, as: :text
```

As you can see, using the "as: :text" will use a text_area field, but if you want to modify the amount of rows and cols you should do it like this:

```
f.input :foobar, as: :text, input_html: {rows: 10, cols: 10}
```

Here you can see the documentation for the gem:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: You can switch from hashrockets to symbol assignment and have `f.input :foobar, as: :text, input_html: {rows: 10, cols: 10}`